# jQuery - Disable href based on checkbox - Location of script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, href

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but I am very much a novice with javascript and html so probably a lot.  I am trying to enable / disable an href link based on the selection of the check box.  Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"/>
<meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2" />
<meta http-equiv="description" content="Description of Page" />
<link href="css/style.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style2 {
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style3 {
    font-family: Neogrey;
}
</style>
<script type="jQuery">
$('#link').click(function(){return false; });
$('#check').click(function() {
  if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
    $('#link').bind('click', function(){ return false; });
  }else{
    $('#link').unbind('click');
  }
});</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="auto-style2">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="logo"><h1 class="auto-style3">
</h1></div>
<h2 class="head">Header Text</h2>
<div class="auto-style1">
Welcome Text.<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check"/><label for="check">I accept the <a href="TC.html">Terms of Service</a>.</label>
<br />
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="link">
<img alt="" height="30" src="images/download.png" width="100" /></a><br />

</div>
<div class="footer">
<div class="menu">
<a href="iOS-TC.html">iOS</a>
    <a href="android-TC.html">Android</a>
    <a href="blackberry-TC.html">Blackberry</a>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Support</a>
</div>
</div>
</form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to include jQuery. Add this above your javascript: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` (and `script type` should be `text/javascript`)

Answer (score 4):

Once you've included jQuery, I'd suggest making use of the DOM to make the script a little more efficient:

```
// bind the click-handler:
$('#link').click(function(e){
    // prevent the default action of clicking on a link:
    e.preventDefault();
    // if the element with id 'check' is checked:
    if (document.getElementById('check').checked){
        // change the window.location to the 'href' of the clicked-link:
        window.location = this.href;
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dE3Hb/).

This would lead to the following HTML of your `<head>` element:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"/>
<meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2" />
<meta http-equiv="description" content="Description of Page" />
<link href="css/style.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
/* CSS removed for brevity */
</style>
<!-- note that this must come before the script containing the jQuery code
     which in this case follows immediately -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="jQuery">
$('#link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (document.getElementById('check').checked){
        window.location = this.href;
    }
});
</script>

</head>
```

Alternatively (though you *still need to include jQuery*), you could use the following approach:

```
// binds a change-handler function to the check-box:
$('#check').change(function () {
    /* adds the 'disabled' class to the '#link' element if
       the '#check' element is _not_ checked, and removes the
       class if the '#check' element _is_ checked: */
    $('#link').toggleClass('disabled', !this.checked);
/* triggers the change event-handler (so the class-name is toggled
   appropriately on page-load: */
}).change();

/* attaches a delegated click-handler to the 'body' element,
   if the click occurs on an 'a' element with the 'disabled'
   class the function is executed:
*/
$('body').on('click', 'a.disabled', function(e){
    // the default behaviour is prevented
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dE3Hb/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).
- [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location).

Answer (score 1):

Put the following line in between your  and  tags to be able to use jquery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Change your line that says:

```
<script type="jQuery">
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/uAMt7/)</kbd>

As Tom Gerken was the first to point out, you must include the jQuery library as he demonstrated in his answer. This is really the key point in solving your problem and Tom should receive credit for the correct solution.

However, here is another approach for enabling/disabling the link:

Begin with your href set to `"#"`, as in:

```
<a href="#" id="link">
```

Your jQuery code block would do this:

```
$('#check').click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        $('#link').attr('href','http://www.google.com');
    }else{
        $('#link').attr('href','#');
    }
});
```

---

**Full Code Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"/>
<meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2" />
<meta http-equiv="description" content="Description of Page" />
<link href="css/style.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #4d4d4d;
        line-height: 2em;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .auto-style2 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .auto-style3 {
        font-family: Neogrey;
    }
</style>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

            <style>
            </style>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    $('#link').click(function(){return false; });

                    $('#check').click(function() {
                        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
                            $('#link').attr('href','http://www.google.com');
                        }else{
                            $('#link').attr('href','#');
                        }
                    });
                }); //END $(document).ready()

            </script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="auto-style2">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="logo"><h1 class="auto-style3">
</h1></div>
<h2 class="head">Header Text</h2>
<div class="auto-style1">
Welcome Text.<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check"/><label for="check">I accept the <a href="TC.html">Terms of Service</a>.</label>
<br />
<a href="#" id="link">
<img alt="" height="30" src="images/download.png" width="100" /></a><br />

</div>
<div class="footer">
<div class="menu">
<a href="iOS-TC.html">iOS</a>
    <a href="android-TC.html">Android</a>
    <a href="blackberry-TC.html">Blackberry</a>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Support</a>
</div>
</div>
</form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apply the correct href to the link, so the link still works when JS is disabled.

Comment: I see your point. Begin with the correct link in HTML, then disable it on document.ready with js, then re-enable with js when checkbox is checked. This may not be what the OP would want -- it would allow users to circumvent the agreement by disabling js before coming to the site, yes?

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I am still having trouble and wonder now if it may be tied to Microsoft Expression Web 4 somehow.  I have copied and pasted the code above as well as added the jQuery as numerous have suggested, but am still not having success when previewing the page with IE, Chrome, or Firefox.  I have also tried the jsFiddle examples with the same result.  They work great in jsFiddle, but fall apart when I put them in my code.

Comment: You should create a test page with just enough elements on it to test that the basic jQuery does work. Also, immediately inside the document.ready wrap, add a line like `alert('hi');` and see if a messagebox pops up immediately upon page view / page refresh. If not, then you might have an error in your js/jQ somewhere. Remember that a single error (missing comma, extra brace, etc) will break ALL the javascript/jQuery. Nothing will work until you find/fix that broken bit. Best solution is to reduce / test / fix.